# Can't update user on the server but works on localhost using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite, service

I'm working on an API and a lot of it works great, but for some reason I cannot update the members.

This is the route:

```
    Route::prefix('member')->group(function () {
    Route::post('login', [App\Http\Controllers\Api\MemberAuthController::class, 'login']);
    Route::post('register', [App\Http\Controllers\Api\MemberAuthController::class, 'register']);

    Route::middleware('auth:member_api', 'member.auth.api')->group(function () {
        Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\Api\MemberAuthController::class, 'getMember']);
        Route::put('/', [App\Http\Controllers\Api\MemberController::class, 'update']);
```

Auth works great, I login, get token, paste the token and I send the PUT request to my localhost or server.

When I send the request to the localhost, I get the updated member back, but when I send request to the server I get the member as it was and it's still the same in the database.

This is the `MemberController` update method:

```
 * @param string $locale The locale setting (e.g., 'en-us')
 * @param Request $request
 * @param MemberService $memberService
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
 */
public function update(string $locale, Request $request, MemberService $memberService)
{
    $member = $request->user('member_api');

    $data = $request->only(['name', 'email', 'password', 'street_name_number', 'city', 'zipcode', 'phone']);

    $updatedMember = $memberService->update($member, $data);

    return response()->json(['member' => $updatedMember], 200);
```

And this is the MemberService update method

```
 * @param Member $member
 * @param array $data
 * @return Member
 */
public function update(Member $member, array $data): Member
{
    if (isset($data['password'])) {
        $data['password'] = bcrypt($data['password']);
    }

    $member->update($data);

    return $member->fresh();
}
```

I thought it would be simple, but I have no idea why it ain't working.

Edit: tried on two separate servers, it's one of those finished laravel apps with web application and api part. This API part needed some extending and all was well until the update method

This is the top part of member model where properties are:

```
class Member extends Authenticatable implements HasLocalePreference, HasMedia

use HasApiTokens, Notifiable, InteractsWithMedia, HasIdentifier, HasCustomShortflakePrimary, HasSchemaAccessors;

/**
 * The table associated with the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'members';

/**
 * The attributes that should be cast.
 *
 * @var array<string, string>
 */
protected $casts = [
    'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    'last_login_at' => 'datetime',
    'meta' => 'array',
    'created_at' => 'datetime',
    'created_at' => 'datetime',
    'deleted_at' => 'datetime',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should not be exposed by API and other public responses.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hiddenForPublic = [
    'affiliate_id',
    'role',
    'member_number',
    'display_name',
    'birthday',
    'gender',
    'two_factor_enabled',
    'two_factor_secret',
    'two_factor_recovery_codes',
    'account_expires_at',
    'premium_expires_at',
    'country_code',
    'phone_prefix',
    'phone_country',
    'phone',
    'phone_e164',
    'is_vip',
    'is_active',
    'accepts_text_messages',
    'is_undeletable',
    'is_uneditable',
    'number_of_emails_received',
    'number_of_text_messages_received',
    'number_of_reviews_written',
    'number_of_ratings_given',
    'meta',
    'media',
    'deleted_at',
    'deleted_by',
    'created_by',
    'updated_by'
];

public function hideForPublic() 
{
    $this->makeHidden($this->hiddenForPublic);

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Allow mass assignment of a model.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $guarded = [];

/**
 * Append programmatically added columns.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $appends = [
    'avatar',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
 *
 * @var array<int, string>
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password',
    'remember_token',
];

public function newEloquentBuilder($query)
{
    return new MemberQueryBuilder($query);
}

/**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Greetings all who wander here,

To answer this old question (Sorry, I've been in rush so I forgot to post the solution)

For some reason, nothing worked until I simply used $request->all(), and later on I added avatar so it looks like this:

```
public function update(Request $request, MemberService $memberService)
{
    $member = $request->user('member_api');

    $avatar = $request->file('avatar');

    $data = $request->except(['avatar']);
    Log::info($avatar, $data);
    $updatedMember = $memberService->update($member, $data);

    if ($avatar) {
        $memberService->updateAvatar($member, $avatar);
    }

    return response()->json(['member' => $updatedMember], 200);
}
```

Hope this will help another Laravel developer :D

Thank you all for help in the above responses!

Answer (score 2):

As far as the code snippet you shared, I think that should do the work. However, what I think is probably wrong is the Member model; I know I can't see the content right now but you might want to check `fillable` to see if the columns you're trying to update are in the `fillable` property of the model. I would assume, they are not in the `guarded` property of the model.

In case you didn't know, and this is still based off my assumption, to mass update attributes in laravel, you'll have to include them in `fillable` or at least exclude the ones you don't want to be mass updated by including them in the `guarded` property of the model. It's important to note that you should either use one out of `guarded` and `fillable`, the one that better suits your need.

```
/**
 * Properties that you want to be mass assignable
 */
protected $fillable = [
  'name', 
  'email', 
  'password', 
  'street_name_number', 
  'city', 
  'zipcode', 
  'phone'
]
```

OR

```
/**
 * Properties that you don't want to be mass assigned.
 */
protected $guarded = [
 'column_1'
]
```

Comment: Since this is the project of some company that don't even have customer support, I thought they made the model as it should be, but now when you said it - it totally makes sense.

I edited the question so you can see that part of the model, what do you think about it, should I add the $fillable properties?

Comment: The thing is, I had $guarded = [] which means all is mass assignable and I don't think it should be an issue when everything's alright local but not on the server

Comment: @PhantomPhreak1995 you're right. However, code could sometimes behave differently in different environment either by an underlying issue or by design. But not to over digress, I don't think you should be opening up an important model like this 100% with the `$guarded = []`. But right now I can't see any issue. Have you tried to set $fillable just for the sake of testing?

Comment: Also, as an addition, dd your way to the very end of the request, it could help.

Comment: I logged everything and it seems that my $request is empty
It goes through authorization, gets the member based on the token, but the $data is empty!
$data = $request->all(); - also tried with $request['property1', 'property2' etc.]

Answer (score 1):

I see your problem, but I didn't see the cause. I can assume that there is some global logic. I can offer you a simple solution, use the `find()` method instead of `fresh`.

```php
public function update(Member $member, array $data): Member
{
    if (isset($data['password'])) {
        $data['password'] = bcrypt($data['password']);
    }

    $member->update($data);

    return Member::query()->find($member->id); // same fresh
}
```